# PHP & MYSQL Display current inserted value in a pop up after submitting the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

when we are inserting the value there is a column name code that is auto generating in mysql. I want to display the last inserted value code column in pop up window.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
require_once 'db.php';

// Escape user inputs for security
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($test_db, $_POST['company']);
$project = mysqli_real_escape_string($test_db, $_POST['project']);
$revision = mysqli_real_escape_string($test_db, $_POST['revision']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO live (company, project, revision, code) VALUES ('$company', '$project', '$revision', '')";
if(mysqli_query($test_db , $sql)){
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("i want to show last inserted code here and redirected to a page on clicking close button"); 
            </script>'; 

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($test_db);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($test_db);
?>
```

Comment: I don't get what you actually mean

Comment: your question description is not at all clear.

Comment: actually i want to display last inserted value in pop up window

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "live" table has a primary key auto-increment column, then this should work:

```
if(mysqli_query($test_db , $sql)){
echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("ID of last inserted row: '.mysqli_insert_id($test_db).'"); 
        </script>'; 
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked. but i want to display it in few seconds and return to main page

Comment: @IRSHADJABBAR so you want to confirm to the user that their data was inserted, and then redirect them? Personally I would only do the redirect once you know that the user has acknowledged the message (e.g. by clicking ok on the alert). Otherwise, if they turn away from their screen for a few seconds for any reason, they might miss the confirmation and be confused, and maybe think the data hasn't been inserted successfully.